# Cannot figure out "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Tags: python

I am trying to convert Accelerated Data into gravity but an error pops up at line 5 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float''

```
1. l = []
2. for i in df3.values:
3.   m = []
4.   for x in i:
5.     x = ((2*8)/(pow(2,14)))*x
6.     m.append(x)
7.   l.append(m)
8. df3 = pd.DataFrame(l)
9. print(df3)
```

the csv file contains Acceleration Data (x, y, z vector) int bits and I am trying to convert it into acceleration,
example:

```
76,-697,-279
15,-174, -90
-53,-568,-306
48,-675,-254
1,-176, -81
-84,-613,-271
-2,-668,-221
-10,-180, -77
```

Comment: why are you using the same variable for your iterator `for x in i` and then you are using it to assign some values to it? (and multiply by it)

Comment: you probably want to use `numpy.array` for your intermediate arrays not a native Python list, which won't behave nicely with things like multiplication (where it makes soft copies)

Comment: Why recalculate those constants? It's not that expensive, but still, why not just use `0.0009765625`? Also, what are you trying to do, exactly? You're clearly applying some kind of calculation on a DataFrame. Can you provide a sample DataFrame for us? I see no reason to be using a nested for loop here.

Comment: Are you trying to get the magnitude of the acceleration vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions, perhaps you have accelerometer data like [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201755/what-are-the-units-of-the-measurements-that-come-out-of-an-accelerometer)

Instead of using a loop, you may be able to do this directly with vectorized math

```py
df = df.assign(gravity=(df["source"] / 1024))
```

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'source': [200, 10000, 20000, 900]})
>>> df.assign(gravity=df['source']/1024)
   source    gravity
0     200   0.195312
1   10000   9.765625
2   20000  19.531250
3     900   0.878906
```

Comment: Why not just divide by 1024?

Comment: ah, intermediate math gaffe

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you're asking for, but it seems like maybe you want the magnitude of those acceleration vectors? In that case, use `df.apply(np.linalg.norm, axis=1)`, like so:

```py
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
    x    y    z
0  76 -697 -279
1  15 -174  -90
2 -53 -568 -306
3  48 -675 -254
4   1 -176  -81
5 -84 -613 -271
6  -2 -668 -221
7 -10 -180  -77

In [4]: df.apply(np.linalg.norm, axis=1)
Out[4]:
0    754.603207
1    196.471372
2    647.355389
3    722.803569
4    193.747258
5    675.474648
6    703.611398
7    196.033160
dtype: float64
```